# CSS layout for 3 sections, with side section width of content and middle section width consuming remaining

Tags: html, css

Basically I want to layout a toolbar with some icons on the left and right and a variable sized text field in the middle. I want the text field to take up the remaining space in the middle. The side sections widths are not known ahead of time, they are determined by the number of visible buttons on each side.

The problem is similar to http://www.alistapart.com/d/holygrail/example_4.html except he side column widths can not be hardcoded.

Is it possible to do this purely in CSS?

Comment: Is there at least a max-width that you can specify for the sidebars?

Comment: I hate to say it, but maybe a table would work?

Comment: Why was this question voted down?

Comment: No worries, no idea, but it's not anymore

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need `display:table-cell`

http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp

Container can be `display:table-row` and the children can be `display:table-cell`. I believe that should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, if you're using a browser that supports the flexible box layout model, setting the left and right DIVs to "-webkit-box-flex: 0;" and the center DIV to "-webkit-box-flex: 1;" does exactly what I want. The container should have "display: -webkit-box;"